# Why the installing process of R package "RODBC" in "R CMD INSTALL" can't find ODBC driver manager?

Tags: sql, r, debian, vertica, rodbc

I am trying to connect to an Vertica DB from R using "**RODBC**" package. Also, the machine I am using is an remote server which doesn't have direct internet access so I basically "transfer" all source files from my local to the remote server to build the system. So, in order to give you an clear context, I am listing all my steps in attending of installing "**RODBC**" package below:

**Step1** - I downloaded the ***RODBC_1.3-13.tar.gz*** source file for **RODBC** and then tried to directly install it with "**R CMD INSTALL**". However, I encountered error as "***ODBC headers sql.h and sqlext.h not found***".
[image]

**Step2** - After a few researches, I found that the installation of "**unixodbc-dev**" would potentially solve this issue. Therefore, I downloaded all needed dependencies for "**unixodbc-dev**" and transferred them to the server. As you can see the list:
[image]

Therefore, I also successfully installed "**unixodbc-dev**":
[image]

However, another error message appears when I tried to re-install the "**RODBC**" using "***sudo R CMD INSTALL /home/mli/RODBC_1.3-13.tar.gz***" in which it returns error "**no ODBC driver manager found**":

[image]

As the message indicates, the installation program can't locate my ODBC driver manager. So, I downloaded "***vertica-client-7.2.3-0.x86_64.tar.gz***" and unzipped it on the server:

[image]

So, now my question is how can I customize the "**R CMD INSTALL**" command say, using some parameter handles to direct the installation program to locate the driver manager? Or am I trying this in a right direction? Please let me know. Any help would be really appreciated!!! :)

**ADDITION**:
I have also tried it with **JDBC** in which the I successfully loaded the "**RJDBC**" package in R and used the **JDBC** driver from **vertica-client-7.2.3-0.x86_64.tar.gz**. Also, I have already had "**rJava**" installed. However, I have still got an error when I tried to make the connection. I am listing my result below:

I successfully installed the "**RJDBC**" with "***$R CMD INSTALL RJDBC_0.2-5.tar.gz --library=/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/***" and then I tried the following scripts in **R**. All the lines are successfully executed except on the line 16:

[image]

Based on the error message, I assumed the version of the **JDBC** driver that I was using is too new for the Vertica server. So, I was trying to use an older version **JDBC** driver instead, like the "**vertica-jdk5-6.1.0-0.jar**" which I have downloaded from this link:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/v/Downloadverticajdk56100jar.htm
So, I moved the file "**vertica-jdk5-6.1.0-0.jar**" to my home directory on the server and then changed the **JDBC** driver path in the **R** script:

[image]

As you can see, it still returns error "**FATAL: Unsupported frontend protocol 3.6: server supports 3.0 to 3.5**". Am I doing it right? Or is there an issue with the new driver that I downloaded? How can make it works? Please, any help will be really appreciated! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

*First*, just do `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rodbc`.  The package was created (by yours truly) in no small part because dealing with unixODBC or iODBC is not fun.  But even once you have that, you still need the ODBC driver for Linux from Vertica.  And that part is filly.

*Second*, I just did something similar the other day but just used JDBC, which worked. You do of course need `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava` which has its own can of worms (but I already mentioned Java...) Still, maybe try that instead?

*Third*, you can cheat and just use `psql` pointed to the Vertica port (usually one above the PostgreSQL port).

Comment: Thank you so much for listing all the options! Yes, I totally agree! It is really no fun;( I was actually trying to do it with the JDBC instead but I am also stuck by an error. I updated my original post with more detail regarding my issue when using JDBC. Please let me know if this is something you would be able to help. Again, thanks Dirk!